# -28115-ORA-28115: policy with check option violation

Tags: error-handling, policy, policy-violation

When I try to Merge data, -28115-ORA-28115: policy with check option violation , I am getting this error. How to solve this. Which team will handle this error. Thanks
I am trying in new database, the code runs fine in old database schema.